# Search query does not written array object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-scout

I am working in Laravel 5.4. I have written a search query and it works fine. But it does not return array object.

It return like below data:

```
"user" : {
     2: {
        "id":2,
        "firstname":"xyz"
     },
     3: {
        "id":31,
        "firstname":"abc"
     },
     5: {
        "id":42,
        "firstname":"pqr"
     }
}
```

But I need array like below:

```
"user" : [
     {
        "id":2,
        "firstname":"xyz"
     },
     {
        "id":31,
        "firstname":"abc"
     },
     {
        "id":42,
        "firstname":"pqr"
     }
}
```

I have written query like :

```
User::search($request->data)->paginate(5);
```

In model I have write code as :

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{        
    return array_only($this->toArray(), ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname']);    
}
```

So what code should I have to change to return as per the required data?

**Note:** I have tried **toArray()** but it does not work.

Comment: Might help to show what your `search` code is like. Most likely `User::search($request->data)->values()->paginate(5)` will work but not sure.

Comment: @apokryfos it gives an error as `Call to undefined method Laravel\Scout\Builder::values()`.

Comment: I don't see scout supporting this out of the box then. You can probably get the paginated results page as a collection and do a `->values()` on that but that's a bit shady.

Comment: @apokryfos I have same query in the same function. It returns perfect with paginate but this query does not return.

Comment: It's probably because this is getting a result and then it's filtering it. It's not the same as a normal eloquent query, it probably tries to keep the indexes matched with what the equivalent eloquent query would return.

Comment: @apokryfos So, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you share the piece of code that generates the data you are showing?

Comment: Can you show your configuration or customzation in your User model?

Comment: @gentcys I have update question please check it.

Comment: Did you filter the result after `User::search($request->data)->paginate(5);`?

Comment: @gentcys No, i do not filter after writing search query.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar May be you remove items in indexs`0, 1, 4` of `users`, and the result auto convert to object instead of array.

Comment: @gentcys I have written same query for another model and its work fine and i do not do anything after writing this query.